# Why the leading behavior of this function is like that?

Tags: calculus, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

I am reading this [note](http://people.bath.ac.uk/pam28/Paul_Milewski,_Professor_of_Mathematics,_University_of_Bath/Past_Teaching_files/stirling.pdf), which is to derive Gaussian distribution from Binomial. But I am confused by one step:

$$\ln p \\\sim ln\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}-\frac{1}{2}\ln n-\frac{1}{2}\ln(1-\frac{m^2}{n^2})-\frac{m}{2}\ln(1+\frac{m}{n})\\ \sim\ln\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}-\frac{1}{2}\ln n+\frac{m^2}{2n^2}+\frac{m^2}{2n}-\frac{m^2}{n}$$

That is, $\ln$$(1$$-\frac{m^2}{n^2})$ can be substituted by $\frac{m^2}{n^2}$. And it is explained as leading behavior. But I can't understand how it can be derived. Could you please help me with this problem?

Comment: Do you know the Taylor series expansion of the natural logarithm?

Comment: @B.Pasternak I know Taylor series expansion, but don't know Taylor series expansion of ln. I just googled it and know how it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Good. I'll post an answer so this doesn't stay unanswered.

Comment: @B.Pasternak Thanks for your work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Taylor series expansion for the log is $log(1-x)=-x+\mathcal{O}(x^2)$ (as long as $|x|<1$), so $\frac{m^2}{n^2}$ is the leading behavior of $-\ln(1-\frac{m^2}{n^2})$.